# Missing window in QGIS 3.4.9 Madeira

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, fields-attributes

I am working with the latest stable version QGIS 3.4.9 Madeira. Unfortunately, I cannot find the window relating to projected coordinate system properties (see the picture), so I cannot change the coordinates of the central meridian. Can you help me, please?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are using QGIS? The image shown in your question looks like from ArcGIS.

Comment: I think it was looking for the equivalent ArcGIS window in QGIS, so showing this picture as an example. Maybe rephrase a little bit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screenshot of the window for QGis Madeira.
The highlighted areas are the place where to open the SRID (Spatial Reference Identifier) and where to define it in the window.

[image]